# Will this slotted waste fit this basin?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

I am buying a basin and it isnt clear if the waste will fit it?
How do you ensure the slot for the overflow is at the right location? (or are they all the same? )

[Basin](https://www.tradingdepot.co.uk/vitra-s20-60cm-washbasin-1th-5503#tech-specs)

[Waste](https://www.tradingdepot.co.uk/burlington-click-clack-bsn-waste-slotted-w11#tech-specs)

Answer (score 1):

They're all more or less standard these days. The overflow comes in between the upper and lower rings on the drain. I've never seen one that didn't work.